# I am trying to find out how to convert python code to pseudocode, it seems easy with other code but I am not sure about my own

Tags: python, pseudocode

I am still working with the same code as before (I will post lower), I just need help converting the first 10-15 lines to pseudocode so I have an idea on how to do it myself.

Code works, indents are weird because I quickly added spaces to put into code.
Apologies for the non professional code, I am still new to python!
Also, please don't do the whole of the pseudocode, just upto the end of the first while true loop so I can figure it out and do the rest myself. thank you :)

```
#Taran Gill - S1714318

#Please Open in Python and not IDLE

#Code for car hire

import sys
import pc
from datetime import date
import time
import os
def restart_program():
python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

#Opening Statement

while True:
    opening = input("Welcome, would you like to hire a car? Please state 
'Yes' or 'No'\n")
  if opening.lower() == 'yes':
        print ("Thats good! First we need to take some details")
        break
  if opening.lower() == 'no':
        print ("Hope you have a good day!")
        print ("Exiting...")
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
        break
  else:
        print ("Invalid answer")
        print ("Restarting...")
        time.sleep(1)
        restart_program()
        continue

#Asks user for First Name

correct_name1 = False
while correct_name1 == False:
    firstName = input("Please enter your First Name\n")
if (firstName.replace (' ','').isalpha()==False):
    print("Not Acceptable")
    continue
    print ("Your First Name is", firstName.title())
while True:
    correct1 = input("Is this correct?\n")
    if correct1.lower() == "yes":
        correct_name1 = True
        break
    if correct1.lower() == "no":
        correct_name1 = False
        break
    else:
        print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks user for Last Name

correct_name2 = False
while correct_name2 == False:
    lastName = input("Please enter your Last Name\n")
if (lastName.replace (' ','').isalpha()==False):
    print("Not Acceptable")
    continue
    print ("Your Last Name is", lastName.title())
while True:
        correct2 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct2.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name2 = True
              break
        if correct2.lower() == "no":
              correct_name2 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks user for House Number

correct_name3 = False
while correct_name3 == False:
  try:
        houseNumber = int(input("Please enter your House Number\n"))
        if houseNumber < 1 or houseNumber > 2500:
              print ("Please put a number in between 1 and 2500")
              continue
        print ("Your House Number is", houseNumber)
  except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Format")
        continue
  while True:
        correct3 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct3.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name3 = True
              break
        if correct3.lower() == "no":
              correct_name3 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks user for Street Name

correct_name4 = False
while correct_name4 == False:
  try:
        streetName = input("Please enter your Street Name\n")
        if (len(streetName) <=4 or streetName.replace (' ','').isalpha()==False):
            print("Not Acceptable")
            continue
        print ("Your Street Name is", streetName.title())
  except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Format")
        continue
  while True:
        correct4 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct4.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name4 = True
              break
        if correct4.lower() == "no":
              correct_name4 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks user for City

correct_name5 = False
while correct_name5 == False:
  try:
        city = input("Please enter your City\n")
        if (len(city) <3 or city.replace (' ','').isalpha()==False):
            print("Not Acceptable")
            continue
        print("Your City is",city.title())
  except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Format")
        continue
  while True:
        correct5 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct5.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name5 = True
              break
        if correct5.lower() == "no":
              correct_name5 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")


#Asks user for Post Code

correct_name6 = False
while correct_name6 == False:
  postcode = input ("Please enter your Post Code\n")
  try:
        checkpc = pc.parse_uk_postcode(postcode)
  except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Post Code, Please try again")
        continue
  else:
        print ("Your Post Code is", postcode.upper())
  while True:
        correct6 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct6.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name6 = True
              break
        if correct6.lower() == "no":
              correct_name6 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks user for Date Of Hire

correct_name7 = False
while correct_name7 == False:
  dateOfHire = input("Please enter the date of start of hire in the format - dd/mm/yyyy\n")
  try:
        valid_date = time.strptime(dateOfHire, '%d/%m/%Y')
  except ValueError:
        print("Invalid format, please try again")
        continue
  else:
        print("The date of start of hire is", dateOfHire)
  while True:
        correct7 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct7.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name7 = True
              break
        if correct7.lower() == "no":
              correct_name7 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks the user for the Amount of Days they would like to hire the car for

correct_name8 = False
while correct_name8 == False:
  try:
        amountOfDays = int(input("Please enter the amount of days you would like to hire for\n"))
        if amountOfDays <1 or amountOfDays > 100:
            print ("Please enter a sensible number!")
            continue
  except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Format")
        continue
  else:
        print ("The amount of days you would like to hire the vehicle is", amountOfDays, "days")
  while True:
        correct8 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct8.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name8 = True
              break
        if correct8.lower() == "no":
              correct_name8 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Tells the user what the prices are for each vehicle

print ("""
Estate costs 50 pounds a day
Saloon costs 60 pounds a day
Sports costs 70 pounds a day
There will be an additional 10 pound charge for each day
if the estimated miles is above 100 miles
""")

#Asks the user what vehicle they want

correct_name9 = False
while correct_name9 == False:
  car = input("Would you like an Estate, Saloon or Sports?\n")  
  if car.lower() in ["estate", "saloon", "sports"]:
        print("The car you have chosen is", car.title())
  else:
        print ("Invalid car, please try again")
        continue
  while True:
        correct9 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct9.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name9 = True
              break
        if correct9.lower() == "no":
              correct_name9 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Asks the user how many miles they think they will do in a day

correct_name10 = False
while correct_name10 == False:
  try:
        estMiles = int(input("How many miles do you think you will do in a day?\n"))
        if estMiles < 1 or estMiles > 1500:
            print ("Please enter a sensible number!")
            continue
  except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Format")
        continue
  else:
        print ("The amount of miles you think you will do in a day is", estMiles)
  while True:
        correct10 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct10.lower() == "yes":
              correct_name10 = True
              break
        if correct10.lower() == "no":
              correct_name10 = False
              break
        else:
              print ("Please say yes or no")

#Calculations for each vehicle

if car == "estate":
  calculation = 50 * amountOfDays
elif car == "saloon":
  calculation = 60 * amountOfDays
elif car == "sports":
  calculation = 70 * amountOfDays

if estMiles > 100:
  calculation = calculation + (10*amountOfDays)

print ("It will cost you", calculation, "pounds.")

#Lets the user decide if they want to input another vehicle or exit

while True:
    answer = input("Type restart to start over, type exit to exit program\n")
if answer.lower() == 'restart':
    print ("Restarting...")
    time.sleep(1)
    restart_program()
elif answer.lower() == 'exit':
    print ("Exiting...")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit
    break
else:
    print ("Invalid Format, Please try again")
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pseudo code? I'd try and read up a bit on Python, its really not hard to understand what is going on. Basically:

`import` imports various python modules needed in this code.
`def restart_program():` defines a function which you can run later in the code with `restart_program()`
`While True:` means do something forever, or until `break`
`.lower()` is the lowercase version of the string

If you're using this code as a basis, it is not particularly pythonic, it uses a style like an old linear basic program, with an overuse of While True loops. There is definitely much shorter and more readable ways of writing the same program.

Comment: this is the code i wrote as an exam, but for homework he wants us to write it up in pseudocode. it had to be a procedural program so while true loops is the one we had to do. i just need help in a few lines thats all. i understand everything i wrote its just the pseudocode im having trouble writing.